# What is Tip Selection Algorithm for Byteball, Dagcoin and HCash

Tags: algorithm, cryptocurrency

I am on Tip Selection algorithm now.

IOTA Tangle (DAG) uses *MCMC* (Markov Chain Monte Carlo) algorithm as a tip selection algorithm. (mentioned in IOTA whitepaper)

But the other DAG based systems like Byteball, Dagcoin, and HCash doesn't mention about its own Tip selection algorithm. (On the whitepapers)

> Does it mean the DAG based systems use same Tip Selection Algorithm
>   (MCMC)?

Tip selection algorithm is very important for its privacy and secure.

If the systems use any special Tip Selection Algorithm, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the Byteball whitepaper. It just doesn't use the phrase 'tip selection algorithm '.

Comment: I checked Byteball whitepaper before. but there is only this part that main chain is changed according to selection tip. Would you let me know the part exactly? @user898617